# Can't view the contents of an archived Trello list

Tags: trello, trello-lists

Once a list has been archived in Trello, I need the ability to see which cards are inside that list from inside the archive.

I don't want to press "send to board" on all of the lists. The archive doesn't even show how many cards are within a given list. The only information available about an archived list is a plain text title.

How can I do something like clicking on a list title to view its contents?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's an ugly workaround, but while viewing the archive list, you can search for the list name. That will show you the cards in that list in the search results.

search syntax: `list:"name of archived list"`